# Does the Primitive Obsession code smell apply to Python?

Tags: design, python

Does "primitive obsession" as a poor design practice apply to development in Python? I have seen a lot of examples and discussion in the context of statically typed languages (like Java, C#), but there are also dynamically typed languages like Python. Do solutions to primitive obsession look different in Python without having explicit types?

Comment: This is a really interesting question.  What is the point of a forum if you close every question?  It's OK for people to ask questions even if you don't understand why they are asking.

Comment: @JimmyJames I've been noticing that all day. I had thought that lowering the number of close votes to 3 was a good idea but I'm starting to reconsider. The up side is it only takes 3 to reopen.

Comment: @JimmyJames: This is not a forum though. It's a Q&A site. A forum implies open discussion, which StackExchange is not set up to do, e.g. there no real back-and-forth opportunity here. Other than an errant comment for clarification, it's a straight "ask question, give answer" flow. This comes with some rigidity as to how questions should be formed. If you want open discussion, and I agree that this has value too, it's better directed at a community with a format more suited to it (e.g. actual forums, a discord group, a reddit-like nested comment format, ...)

Comment: @Flater: I agree 100% to you, However, in this case the OP makes the wrong assumption his question would require a discussion. I think it doesn't. IMHO there are again those usual "buzzword closers" at work, who use a term like "discussion" as a justification for a close vote, without further thinking. But I will do the following now: close the question with the 3rd required vote, edit the buzzword out and vote for reopening it. When the question gets reopened, the system will protect it against closage for a certain time. Maybe I write another answer then, though candied_orange's one is fine.

Comment: @JimmyJames: feel free to cast a reopening vote, if you like.

Comment: @Flater Sorry, my mistake.  What's the point of a Q&A site if you close every question?

Comment: @JimmyJames the need to close questions comes from a need to have a site about a specific something. Something we're known for and can be trusted to be about. Failing to do that actually hurts the sites popularity. However, Ruthlessly closing rather than editing out problematic issues (thank you Doc) or commenting leaves few people willing to even ask questions. Too much in either direction kills the site.

Comment: Is there a better way for me to ask about this topic? Or is the topic off limits entirely?

Comment: @candied_orange I understand all that but it's clear that there are people that frequent this subsite (I won't name them) who are far more concerned with shutting people down than answering questions or helping people.

Comment: @PaulBendevis the close reason given is asking for the question to be more focused. The idea behind that is meant to narrow the question to the point that one good answer can squeeze out others. Otherwise the question receives an endless list of equally correct answers that are rated not on their quality as much as on when they were posted. With that in mind I note that almost all of your sentences end in question marks. Narrow that down and I think your reception will improve.

Comment: @JimmyJames please try not to take it personally. Closing is a thankless job that doesn't exactly pay well. Those who are willing to do it don't seem to want to delve deep before moving on. Their job isn't to fix the problems. It's to shut things down until the problem is fixed. Figuring out how exactly this is a problem is something they rarely give time to explaining. So that leaves it to us.

Comment: @candied_orange It's not personal.  What's considered a 'good' question seems pretty subjective to me.  For example how is this less focused than 'does GC scan the entire memory'?  This isn't stackoverflow. Software Engineering isn't just about 'hard' technical things.

Comment: @JimmyJames it is subjective. But it's the best we can do. We have over 2000 questions on meta trying to sort it out. I've been here over 8 years and still haven't read them all. I expect few have. So it's not going to be perfect. Which is annoying. If you have a better way to do it post it on meta. As it stands close votes fall into canned categories to force closers to say *something* when they close. It's not comprehensive. Sometimes the closers don't even agree (wish they'd list all chosen categories). Since leaving a comment so often starts an argument few do. So here we are.

Comment: Arguably, many usages of dictionaries are a form of primitive obsession.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer here is 'yes': primitive obsession is still an issue in dynamically typed languages.  The longer answer is that the issue is somewhat different in a dynamically typed language than a statically-typed one.  I'm going to use Python as an example.

So the first bit of nuance is that in Python and similar languages, there aren't really 'primitives' in the first place.  There are built-in types but they are objects.  I only think we can mostly ignore this, but not completely.  For most intents and purposes, they are used just like primitives are in other languages.

The other nuance is that in a dynamically-typed language, dependencies are not really defined by the type of an object, but rather by the operations it supports.  For (somewhat of a silly)  example, if I have a function that will add all the items in a sequence together, there's nothing stopping me from passing in a list of custom objects that support the `__add__` method.  This effectively means it's harder to create a primitive obsessed API but as Flater noted in comments on another answer, it doesn't prevent you from improperly using 'primitives' in a sub-optimal way.

The most common primitive obsession error (IMO) that I see often is the use of primitive numeric types to represent money.  Using a decimal type is typically better than float, but it's still inappropriate.  Money has special rules and passing it around as a bare number will often result in bugs and hamper the evolution of an application.  For example, I once was talking to someone about an application they were involved in that used integer types for money.  Then later, integer type they used was too small.  They went through and changed all the integers representing money to doubles.  I consider that two mistakes.  So first off, consider trying to find every instance of an integer being used in a financial application and then determine what it's trying to represent.  That's a major PITA in itself.  Instead of using a primitive for money, a better solution is to define a `Money` type.  It can be stupid simple initially: don't over-design things.  But once you've done that, if you need to add a capability such as a wider range or support conversions, you can often fix that in one spot.  And if you need to find all the places it's used, it's far easier to locate.  Can you make a primitive obsession mistake like using base numeric types for money in a dynamically-typed language? Absolutely.

On the other hand, in my experience, dynamically typed languages make reusing existing types easier and I therefore don't feel the need to create as many custom types as I would in a statically-typed language.  But you should still be considering whether a custom type is warranted and largely for the same reasons that you would in a statically-typed language.

Comment: +1 for being willing to wade into the weakly typed issue. For the record, typing based only on what you use is called [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). And your money assessment was, well, on the money.

Comment: @candied_orange You are correct that I am not using correct strong/weak static/dynamic or using the terminology precisely.  I'll try to clean that up.

Answer (score 14):

Primitive obsession is about failing to design a dedicated type that would abstract a concept and instead trying to force an existing type into the role. If  the language in question has customizable types then the smell applies.

The whole static vs dynamic thing is just about where you declare the type. Has nothing to do with primitive obsession.

Comment: But, but, but, type hints aside, how can you be obsessed about a type when it's not necessarily known?

Comment: @JimmyJames The obsession is with existing types. Mostly because one is too lazy to create new ones when they are needed. The primitives get the blame most often because they are simple and flexible. But I have to say, String gets a fair share of obsession itself.

Comment: I just think this is might be a little deeper question that it appears.  Consider truthiness and the issues that can come from that.  I'm not saying the answer is 'no' (I think it applies) but there's some nuance here.

Comment: @JimmyJames Truthiness just makes me think of Stephen Colbert. Are you hinting at type coercion or some other weird magic?

Comment: I think this answer is very succinct and accurate. No nuance here. If you pass two ints and a bool around your program instead of a class that encapsulates them, it's primitive obsession. Full Stop. Whether the language has explicit typing or static typing has no bearing on it

Comment: @candied_orange "truthy" is commonly used to refer to values that are considered equal to true after coercion, yeah

Comment: @JimmyJames The issue isn't with what types are expected, the issue is with what types are being _passed in_ (by the consumer) to represent the needed data. Yes, in strongly typed languages the two are generally equivalent, but not for weakly typed languages. Primitive obsession comes down to "Hmmm, I want to pass [this information] along, which existing type fits best?" => The issue is that the thinker is omitting the concept of **creating their own type** that can perfectly describe the information they're trying to pass, which is the superior option as it leads to better abstraction.

Comment: Truthiness in e.g. Python is like when you `if parameter:` and if the parameter is `None`, then evaluates to `False`.  But so does `0` and so does an empty string.  Also you can override a method in a class that will change this behavior.  So you can do something like create a method designed to accept  an integer but pass in some other object.

Comment: @Flater Interesting but I'm a little dubious.  The things you can successfully pass into a method are determined by the design of the method, not the caller.  In a static language e.g. Java, If the method can only work with primitives you can't just pass in an object.   I'm not sure how you can assert the primitive obsession is defined only by the caller.

Comment: @JimmyJames _"I'm not sure how you can assert the primitive obsession is defined only by the caller."_ Because you explicitly brought that specific topic up: _"how can you be obsessed about a type **when it's not necessarily known?**"_ You've inherently limited your question to cases where the design did not decide the type. By elimination, it must be the caller then. Furthermore, no matter what the designer defines, unless it's a sealed class, the caller is _always_ able to fail to inherit said type in a way that better suits their purpose. Not a primitive then, but the same principle at play

Comment: @Flater Agreed, and we then can infer that weak/strong typing does play into the concept of primitive obsession.

Comment: @JimmyJames: It changes the ways in which someone can use the wrong type for the job, but the principle as to why it's wrong remains unchanged. Besides, even in strongly typed OOP languages you could do exactly the same as in a weakly typed one (by using an overly vague base type such as `object`), so there's no real distinction other than strongly typed languages having more tools available to the designer to disincentivize primitive obsession.

Comment: You guys are starting to confuse me. If my duck typed function insists on adding up things passed to it then the caller has no say on the "type" other than what to try and make work. It's either of the family "stuff you can add up" or it's not. Am I getting that wrong?

Comment: @Flater as I understand it the big distinction is when you get told the type is wrong.

Comment: @candied_orange I'm not totally sure I follow you but with duck-typing, you basically can only enforce "your argument must support adding" whereas in say Java, you can say your "argument must be an integer".  I don't want to put too fine a point on it.  It's not like duck-typing in Python is all rainbows and lollipops.  But I do think it's an extremely important concept.

Comment: @JimmyJames right. And as [Flater points out](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/440475/does-the-primitive-obsession-code-smell-apply-to-python/440477?noredirect=1#comment967199_440477) in Java you don't have to (Integer is an Object). In either case it's the receiver who complains that `add` doesn't exist if it doesn't. Thus it's the receiver who decides what type is acceptable regardless of language static, dynamic, looseness, weakness, or ducks. The caller only gets to decide what concrete type to send. Not if it works.